# SQL alchemy query a single column

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am sure this has been answered before and I see a few related answers but none seem to be the issue I am facing. I am using a SQL Alchemy model that uses a SQL server DB underneath and I am using it to query the DB with a session. The normal queries etc work fine with no errors. However when I ask for only one field instead of all it gives me an error (see later).
Basically boiled down to the simplest I have a model like so:

```
class FactoryShop(Base):
   # case insensitive, refers to the actual table in the DB called factoryshop
   __tablename__ = 'factoryshop'
   ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   Name = Column(String(255))
   Parts = Column(Integer)
   Strength = Column(Integer)
   Average = Column(Float)
   ...
```

Using a session I can query all columns like so:

```
>>> session.query(FactoryShop).filter(FactoryShop.Parts==20000)
<sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x10578c280>
```

However if I try to just ask for the Name like below I get a long error. I searched for that specific error which involves 'selectable' but I didn't come across a relevant answer.

```
>>> session.query(FactoryShop.Name).filter(FactoryShop.Parts==20000)
AttributeError: Neither 'AnnotatedColumn' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'selectable'
```

If there is already an answer please point me to it and I will delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are not querying for it correctly. But you are very close.

```
result = session.query(FactoryShop).filter(FactoryShop.Parts==20000).first()
```

Then, you can call `result.Name` to get the name of that FactoryShop Object.

Comment: I am aware of this but I want to avoid querying all the fields and then get the one I want. It seems like that would be akin to select * from FactoryShop where parts =20000. I want to do select Name from FactoryShop where parts=20000